# Memory Diagnostic Test

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to launch MdSched.exe without having to interact with the GUI that gives 2 clickable options. I am working in C# ASP.NET, and I can launch MdSched.exe via cmd, but I need it to immediately choose the restart now and run test option.

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You want to restart the computer running an ASPI.NET website? From the website? That seems startlingly insecure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes it seems that way.

But the idea has been abandoned due to it being seemingly impossible